# Nginx Webserver not available outside lan http only https works

Tags: http, nginx, https, lan, wan

Im having a strange issue, I have a Nginx webserver running with valid ssl certs on it. On LAN i can access it at http://192.xxx.x.xxx and https://192.xxx.x.xxx no issue but when i go to outside my network i can only access https://example.com the regular http:// connection times out and cant connect.

here is my router port forwards

(name - remote port - lan ip - local port - protocol)

(Webserver80 - 80 - 192.xxx.x.xxx - 80 - TCP)

(Webserver443 - 443 - 192.xxx.x.xxx - 443 - TCP)

I dont get why i can see the http on lan but not wan, and https works fine. 
I Did some open port checks and both are seen by the internet

Success: I can see your service on xx.xx.xx.xx on port (80)
Your ISP is not blocking port 80

Success: I can see your service on xx.xx.xx.xx on port (443)
Your ISP is not blocking port 443

Answer (score 0):

Think I fixed it.

Deleted the port entry in firewall port forward. Rebooted the router and reapplied the port 80... Working now. Odd.